# Books recommendations for a second lecture in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I didn't find questions on second lectures on functional analysis, so I post this.

Last year I took a one semester course in functional analysis and now, this year, I am going to be teaching assistant in that course. I am looking for books for a second lecture in functional analysis that deepen in the topics I saw last year (listed below) and, hopefully, that has a lot of exercises (I like those that are theorems-exercises). Also, I like functional analysis, so any book that might be useful in life also is appreciated.

Last year I learn about:

1. The basics: axioms, completeness, convexity, etc. Chapters 1,2,3 of Rudin's.
2. Duality. Chapters 1,2,3,4 of Robertsons' topological vector spaces.
3. Lots of Banach theory: adjoints, Milman, EberleinSmulian, Kakutani, some embeddings.
4. Some theorems like Banach-Stone, Choquet on convex hull, Mazuerkevi-Sierspinski (this part I didn't understand well)
5. A little on Schrauder bases, Hilberts
6. Spectral theory, mostly from Rudin's
7. Banach's algebras, Gelfan's transform, B* algebras, etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question on this link:

[Book for Functional Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528530/book-for-functional-analysis?rq=1)

I hope it will help you. :)